# Reporting Services Bug and a proposed workaround

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, webforms

I have built a business report that produces quarterly reports of monthly sales for each department, and it seems there is a bug in Microsoft Reporting Services. 
The report template is like

```
Sales report Q[@Quarter]/[@Year]

Department   Month   Sales
[department] [month] [sales]
             Sum     [Sum(sales)]
Overall sum          [Sum(sales)]
```

The data source is an sql query like

```
SELECT department,DATENAME(MONTH(invoiceDate)) AS month,SUM(invoiceAmount) AS sales
FROM sales WHERE ...
ORDER BY department,MONTH(invoiceDate) 
GROUP BY department,MONTH(invoiceDate)
```

Let's assume that Department 1 existed all year, Department 2 was added in December. The generated output is:

```
Department   Month   Sales
Department 1   Oct   $ x
               Nov   $ y
               Dec   $ z
             Sum     $ (x+y+z)
Department 2         $ i
             Sum     $ i
Overall sum          $ (x+y+z+i)
```

You see, a month name is missing in the report. I found this to happen *whenever a department has as the first month the one the previous department has in the last line*, like if a department is substituted in mid-November - it ceases to exist in November, and the new one starts in November, too:

```
Department Month   Sales
OldDept      Oct   $ x
             Nov   $ y
           Sum     $ (x+y)
NewDept            $ z
             Dec   $ i
           Sum     $ (z+i)
Overall sum          $ (x+y+z+i)
```

As far as I can see, this is a bug in Microsoft Reporting Services, right? Or did I just overlook some option?

Otherwise, to work around this, I think the best solution is to make the DLL think that the month names are different - but they shouldn't look different to the user. So I thought, how about adding different amount of whitespace to month names? Since I think whitespace would be used to calculate column width, it shouldn't be too much whitespace for each row. I would have to add just a single space character on every other row. How could I achieve *THAT* in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem.

This is my sample data:

[image: data]

This is how table looks like in SSRS designer:

[image: table]

And this is output:

[image: output]

It looks correct for my. Maybe you've made wrong table in designer ?